# Update specific values within a large array where they match a secondary array (like a vlookup)

Tags: arrays, excel, vlookup, vba

I have been tasked to write a "simple" macro in Excel to perform the following tasks that I can do with VLOOKUPs relatively easily but due to the size of the data can take in some instances a day and totally locks up the PC.

I have a .csv with various headers which I need to interrogate to find and replace values in those columns with headers ending in "_flag".

The "flags" (used to identify confidence levels of the data) have been updated and all the older data needs to be refreshed accordingly.

I have what I refer to as a "FlagMap" that lists the old flag and what the corresponding new flag should be as a separate table.

Normally in Excel I'd have a worksheet (named range) with the FlagMap and the CSV on another tab and put in a dummy column manually next to the column to change and run a VLOOKUP - Have done some of the smaller datasets but given the amount I have to do I'd be retired before I finish (some have 20 columns with "flags" (40 columns in total) and up to 70,000 rows).

I have worked out the process but am really stuck with the coding.

Overall loop of
Find column with heading ending in "_flag"
   If True Loop through vlookup style code to change
     based on if cell in source data = a flag in FlagMap(COL1) replace it with FlagMap(COL2) value
End Change Loop
Next Column

One of the key things is can I replace blank (flags) in the original source data (by specifying a blank entry and corresponding flag in the FlagMap array).

My code is a complete mess as I've tried to build it bit by bit (by recording macros etc.. was looking at using Filters on the columns).

CODE as follows: It doesn't seem to do anything though; brain-hurts....
    Sub FlagUpdate_v00()

```
Dim wsDATA As Worksheet 'original data to be updated
Dim wsFLAG As Worksheet 'Flag mapping lookup sheet
Dim rFLAGMAP As Range 'Flag mapping range n ROWs & 2 COLs(no headers)
Dim rDATA As Range 'Data to update
Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long 'Loop counters
Dim FlagLRow As Long, DataLRow As Long 'last row numbers of corresponding data tables
Dim FlagArray, DataArray, TempArray() As String  'lookup values

Set wsDATA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST") 'assigns location of data
Set wsFLAG = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FlagMap") 'assigns location of flags

'lastrow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
'FlagLRow = wsFLAG.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row 'Sets number of rows upper bound of loop *NOT WORKING
'DataLRow = wsDATA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row 'Sets number of rows upper bound of loop *NOT WORKING
FlagLRow = wsFLAG.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 'Sets number of rows upper bound of loop
DataLRow = wsDATA.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 'Sets number of rows upper bound of loop

Set rFLAGMAP = wsFLAG.Range("A2:A" & FlagLRow) 'sets range of flags to avoiding column header

'this will need to be within a loop to only select range of those columns ending "_Flag"
'Set rDATA = wsDATA.Range(ColLoopRef & "2:A" & DataLRow) 'set range to update
Set rDATA = wsDATA.Range("F2:F" & DataLRow) 'test data only looking at one small column of data

FlagArray = rFLAGMAP.Value 'set contents of array
DataArray = rDATA.Value 'set contents of array

'Loop to replace
 For i = LBound(DataArray) To UBound(DataArray) 'start end values of i loop (Original Flag)
    For j = LBound(FlagArray) To UBound(FlagArray) 'start end values of j loop (FlagMap)
        If DataArray(i, 1) = FlagArray(j, 1) Then 'if Original Data Flag matches the value in the FlagMap
            Set DataArray(i, 1) = FlagArray(j, 2) 'replace it with that from column 2
        End If 'all flags should be Mapped hence always finds one
        'only issue may be blanks!!
    Next j 'loop through the MAPPEDFLAG list (ie. a vlookup) 1st
Next i 'move on to the next DATA flag to be re-flagged


End Sub
```

Thanks to @stucharo for highlighting the exact example I have which is as follows:

Current data set in the form of a CSV

```
   h1        h2     h3_flag      h4     h5_flag      h6
-------------------------------------------------------------
   val1      val2      val3      val4      val5      val6
   val2      val3      val4      val5      val6      val1
   val3      val4      val5      val6      val1      val2
   val4      val5      val6      val1      val2      val3
   val5      val6      val1      val2      val3      val4
   val6      val1      val2      val3      val4      val5
```

Flag Mapping table

```
 flag      alt.   
--------------------
val1      vala
val2      valb
val3      valc
val4      vald
val5      vale
val6      valf
```

Output

```
    h1        h2     h3_flag      h4     h5_flag      h6
-------------------------------------------------------------
   val1      val2      valc      val4      vale      val6
   val2      val3      vald      val5      valf      val1
   val3      val4      vale      val6      vala      val2
   val4      val5      valf      val1      valb      val3
   val5      val6      vala      val2      valc      val4
   val6      val1      valb      val3      vald      val5
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us the code you have so we can help improve or optimize it.

Comment: To optimize this process you might consider treating your source and new data as tables, and query them using the Jet Text file driver with an update query. See [MSDN: Much ADO about Text Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx) and [MS KB: ExcelADO demonstrates how to use ADO to read and write data in Excel workbooks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278973?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: I'm hoping to set up a Macro within excel so using the VB editor in excel and call it from my 'PersonalMacro' set of data (I have others to remove columns and find unique flags)..  Tidying up code as we speak as it was a complete mess!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a piece of code I developed for something similar but I've tweaked a bit to suit your question.  It might need some tidying up since I don't have access to your files to test it with:

```
Sub Flags()

'Assuming your flag map is in a 2 column range in a worksheet
'you can create an array then add it to a collection
'so you can access each entry in col2 by the key from col1
Dim fMap() As Variant
Dim FlagMap As New Collection

fMap = Range("A1:B6") 'range where FlagMap stored

Dim i As Integer        'We can reuse this in other counters....
For i = LBound(fMap) To UBound(fMap)
    FlagMap.Add CStr(fMap(i, 2)), CStr(fMap(i, 1)) 'FlagMap range has "Key" field 1st - assign to Collection correctly
Next i

'Create a FileSystemObject to work with your csv's
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Create a file object to contain your original csv
Dim ifil As Object
Set ifil = fso.GetFile("C:\completepath\myinfile.csv")

'Create a textstream from the input csv file
Dim its As Object
Set its = ifil.OpenAsTextStream()

'We can also output this back into a new csv by
'creating  a textstream to let us write to a new file
Dim ots As Object
Set ots = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\completepath\myoutfile.csv")

'We'll also need a string variable to send to this stream
Dim oStr As String

'Create a counter to keep track of lines through your
'input textstream
Dim lineCounter As Integer
lineCounter = 0

'You can split each line into an array delimited by "," using
'the "Split" function so we need an array variable to hold this
Dim lineArray() As String

'Because this steps through row wise, we also need an
'collection to hold references to the columns of interest
'and a variant to access them again
Dim cols As New Collection
Dim col as Variant

'Continue a loop until you reach the end of your textstream
'i.e. the end of your input csv file
Do While Not its.AtEndOfStream

    'Increment your line counter
    lineCounter = lineCounter + 1
    lineArray = Split(its.ReadLine, ",")

    'If you are on the first row, find all the interesting columns
    If lineCounter = 1 Then ' assuming the headings are on row 1
        For i = LBound(lineArray) To UBound(lineArray)
            'If we find a heading ending in "_flag" then store its
            'column number in the cols collection.
            If Right(lineArray(i), 5) = "_flag" Then
                cols.Add i 'Add ref of where heading "_flag" is to limit lookup just to those areas and not the whole dataset
            End If
        Next i

    'If it's not the first row then process the data as normal
    Else
        'Just look at the columns of interest
        For Each col In cols
            'Replace the value in that column with the corresponding
            'value in the FlagMap
            lineArray(CInt(col)) = FlagMap(lineArray(CInt(col))) 'this is the lookup in the collection based on the "key"
        Next col
    End If

    'Now print the line back out to your new csv file
    oStr = ""
    For i = LBound(lineArray) To UBound(lineArray)
        oStr = oStr + lineArray(i) & ","
    Next i
    oStr = Left(oStr, Len(oStr) - 1)

    ots.WriteLine (oStr)

Loop

'Close the textstreams
its.Close
ots.Close

End Sub
```

[`TextStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242724%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) will let you read and write .csv files in VBA without opening them in excel. [`Collections`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y8b3b3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) allows you to develop `'key':{value}` relationships, which sounds a bit like your FlagMap.